# How do I make it so that Blender would select everything no matter how much zoomed out I am

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, select

[image: Zooming in after the selection]

So If I zoom out and try to select mesh in Edit Mode, I am left with some vertices unselected.
Maybe because of the density of each individual point blender can't select the neighboring vertices.
So how do I select the entire thing even from a distance?
The transparent mode wouldn't help, because I only want to select the outer shell of the model, without touching the insides.

Comment: How are you trying to select and why doesn't just using the A key to "select all" work?

Comment: if you are using a solidify modifier, you should have written that in your question instead of downvoting an answer which would work, but this could nobody know what you are using....

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer.
it's not about solidify even.
I am using CTRL + Mouse over the mesh in edit mode, but because vertex points are too thick it doesn't catch all of the vertices. 
I wanted to know a way around that.
Setting scale of vertex points in interface helps, but only a little bit.

Comment: Can't you use circle or lasso selection to select the outer vertices?

Comment: @blunder you can have similar problems with circle select in dense meshes.